# How to change value in ag-grid when user enters the cell?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have an ag-grid grid with a regular(string) column. When the user enters the cell for editing, I need to change the way the cell value is presented. For example, the column shows "15-Jan-2018" in non-edit mode, but when the user clicks to edit this cell, the text editor that appears should have "2018-01-15" diplayed in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your column definition of this date column you can specify a `cellEditor` or `cellEditorFramework`. Difference between these two is if you use cellEditor you have to register the components and if you use cellEditorFramework you can directly refer to the component class.

```
{
    headerName: "Date",
    field: "date",
    editable: true,
    cellEditor: 'DateEditorComponent'
}
```

or

```
{
    headerName: "Date",
    field: "date",
    editable: true,
    cellEditorFramework: DateEditorComponent
}
```

You can find the documentation about this [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/) 
and an angular example is [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/#angular-cell-editing).